# C#: Can I use Task.Delay directly on a DateTime with a trick? What would be a good alternative?

Tags: c#, datetime, time, integer, delay

Am thinking of

```
...
DateTime dateTimeValueToDelay;
dateTimeValueToDelay = DateTime.Now; //(just an example for a DateTime. Can be any other DateTime)
Task.Delay(dateTimeValueToDelay).ContinueWith(t=> FunctionToExecuteDelayed());
...
```

Obviously, Task.Delay() accepts only int, not DateTime values.

Transforming the DateTime into an int first wont do for larger datetime values (they can consist of values too large to fit into an int) - anyone has a good alternative? I want to execute the FunctionToExecuteDelayed() at a specific DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

I was not aware of the existance of the TimeSpan struct.

```
...
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 8, 0, 25);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2012, 8, 18, 14, 30, 30);
// Calculate the interval between the two dates.
TimeSpan dateTimeValueToDelay= date2 - date1;
...
Task.Delay(dateTimeValueToDelay).ContinueWith(t=> FunctionToExecuteDelayed());
...
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-7.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-7.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-8.0

please be aware of the different .NET versions

Comment: Be mindful that this is still specifying the duration to sleep and not the time to wake.  System clock changes, hibernation or other power-saving modes, and the like can cause the two to diverge.

Comment: Is your thread busy running other code at that 5 second time, or is it pumping messages>

Comment: Actually it did work, but I did not realize that it worked because something else was wrong with my "FunctionToExecuteDeleyed()" - regarding your question, no messages are being "pumped" but of course my program is running other code during these 5 seconds. It's solved as in my answer above, thanks ;)